# Replace data on a specific index in Array List Android

Tags: android, arraylist, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I'm trying to replace the Array list data with the new one, but it always gives me wrong data. First time it replace correctly, but next time in the loop it replace all the index of the Array List. here is my code and log cat in which I'm storing map marker ID's

```
    //Declaring Arraylists
ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>> LatLng_List_for_editing = new ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>>();
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ID_List_for_editing = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
private ArrayList<String> ID_List = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<LatLng> LatLng_List = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

//inserting data

ID_List_for_editing.add(new ArrayList<String>(ID_List));
LatLng_List_for_editing.add(new ArrayList<LatLng>(LatLng_List));

//getting data
for (int p_index = 0; p_index < LatLng_List_for_editing.size(); p_index++) {
                    for (int c_index = 0; c_index < LatLng_List_for_editing.get(p_index).size(); c_index++) {

                        if (ID_List_for_editing.get(p_index).get(c_index).equals(maker_ID_being_draged)) {
                            LatLng_List_for_editing.get(p_index).remove(c_index);
                            LatLng_List_for_editing.get(p_index).add(c_index, ID_latlng);
                            Log.e("Lat lng list during editing :", "" + LatLng_List_for_editing.get(p_index));
                        }
                    }
                    ID_List.clear();
                    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions();
                    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                    polylineOptions.color(Color.RED);
                    polylineOptions.width(3);
                    polylineOptions.addAll(LatLng_List_for_editing.get(p_index));
                    mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
                    for (int lenghth = 0; lenghth < LatLng_List_for_editing.get(p_index).size(); lenghth++) {
                        Marker_ID = mMap.addMarker(
                                marker.position(LatLng_List_for_editing.get(p_index).get(lenghth)).draggable(
                                        true)).getId();
                            ID_List.add(Marker_ID);
                        }
                    Log.e("ID's in edit list is :", "" + ID_List_for_editing);
                    Log.e("ID list before removing :", ":"+p_index + ID_List_for_editing.get(p_index));
                    ID_List_for_editing.remove(p_index);
                        ID_List_for_editing.add(p_index ,ID_List);
                    Log.e("ID list is :", "" + ID_List);
                    Log.e("ID list after removing :", ":"+p_index + ID_List_for_editing.get(p_index));
                    Log.e("IDs in edit list is :", "" + ID_List_for_editing);
                }
                Log.e("final Lat lng list:", "" + LatLng_List_for_editing);
```

And Here is the log cat in which array data is displayed before and after replacement.

```
    09-10 09:25:14.931: E/Start draging Marker(19149): m5
09-10 09:25:16.431: E/new Marker ID coordinates id :(19149): lat/lng: (33.673322993023035,73.07959388941526)
09-10 09:25:16.441: E/ID's in edit list is :(19149): [[m0, m1, m2], [m3, m4, m5]]
09-10 09:25:16.441: E/ID list before removing :(19149): :0[m0, m1, m2]
09-10 09:25:16.441: E/ID list is :(19149): [m6, m7, m8]
09-10 09:25:16.441: E/ID list after removing :(19149): :0[m6, m7, m8]
09-10 09:25:16.441: E/IDs in edit list is :(19149): [[m6, m7, m8], [m3, m4, m5]]
09-10 09:25:16.446: E/Lat lng list during editing :(19149): [lat/lng: (33.672664222061485,73.0725671723485), lat/lng: (33.67516423249219,73.07723086327314), lat/lng: (33.673322993023035,73.07959388941526)]
09-10 09:25:16.451: E/ID's in edit list is :(19149): [[m9, m10, m11], [m3, m4, m5]]
09-10 09:25:16.451: E/ID list before removing :(19149): :1[m3, m4, m5]
09-10 09:25:16.451: E/ID list is :(19149): [m9, m10, m11]
09-10 09:25:16.451: E/ID list after removing :(19149): :1[m9, m10, m11]
09-10 09:25:16.456: E/IDs in edit list is :(19149): [[m9, m10, m11], [m9, m10, m11]]
09-10 09:25:16.456: E/final Lat lng list:(19149): [[lat/lng: (33.66989794278846,73.07382009923458), lat/lng: (33.6673977792688,73.07181749492884), lat/lng: (33.66856443827623,73.0777683109045)], [lat/lng: (33.672664222061485,73.0725671723485), lat/lng: (33.67516423249219,73.07723086327314), lat/lng: (33.673322993023035,73.07959388941526)]]
```

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try **List Interface** and use below method to set the data

```
set(int index, E element)
```

*Replaces the element at the specified location in this List with the specified object. This operation does not change the size of the List.*

**Parameters**

location: the index at which to put the specified object.

object: the object to insert.

**Returns**
    the previous element at the index.

Comment: I've Implemented the same method but same results. The log cat is same as above

Comment: then you debug the app. thats better